# Any way to limit garbage collection of Gen 0, 1 and 2 despite constant bytes in all heaps? And Is this sign of memory leak?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

I was trying to find memory leak in our software and in doing so I have found that, in Windows built in "Performance Monitor" report-

1. Garbage collection of Gen 1 and Gen 2  rises exponentially while
   process is doing some work
2. Garbage collection of Gen 1 & Gen 2 remains constant when process is idle
3. Garbage collection of Gen 0 continues to increase as time passes by irrespective of process is doing some work or not
4. Bytes in all heap shows that it is not increasing over time

Is this normal?

Here is the screen capture of performance report
[image: Performance Monitor report]

Comment: Chart shows total count of garbage collections from the beginning of tracking, it's not a frequency of raising. Also charts are shown in different scaling - look at "Scale" column of the PerfMon. If you beware that GC takes too much time take an appropriate tool and check it. For example [JetBrains dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (in the Timeline mode) will show how much time you app spents for GC.

Comment: How about using "% Time in GC" performance counter for this purpose?

Comment: With full understanding what number it shows - yes.

"Displays the percentage of elapsed time that was spent performing a garbage collection **since the last garbage collection cycle**. This counter usually indicates the work done by the garbage collector to collect and compact memory on behalf of the application. This counter is updated only at the end of every garbage collection. This counter is not an average; its value reflects the last observed value."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went through this MSDN page already, however just wanted to make sure that I am on the correct path. 

As per MSDN - The counter is incremented at the end of a generation 'x' garbage collection. Higher generation garbage collections include all lower generation collections. This counter is explicitly incremented when a higher generation garbage collection occurs.

Can you add this as an answer? I will accept it. :)

Comment: I understand it as this PC is not aggregating, but shows a separated value for each time period from GC to GC. May be I'm wrong, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These charts show total count of garbage collections from the beginning of tracking, it's not a frequency of raising. Also charts are shown in different scaling - look at "Scale" column of the PerfMon. If you beware that GC takes too much time take an appropriate tool and check it. For example [JetBrains dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (in the Timeline mode) will show how much time you app spents for GC.

Also you can use "% Time in GC" performance counter for this purpose.
"Displays the percentage of elapsed time that was spent performing a garbage collection **since the last garbage collection cycle**. This counter usually indicates the work done by the garbage collector to collect and compact memory on behalf of the application. This counter is updated only at the end of every garbage collection. This counter is not an average; its value reflects the last observed value." 
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx